# Android Virtual Device work very slow

Tags: android, android-studio, virtual-machine, android-virtual-device

Hello guys firts of all sorry for my bad English here is my problem.
I am using android studio and the Android virtual device get stuck in android logo (i leave the avd open for 1 day and nothing)
PC Spect:
Windows 10 - 64b Education (is like Enterprise edition)
The S.O is clean i just format build it.
Micro: intel i7
Ram: 8gb DDR3 
Video: GTX 750 TI
HDD: SD Kingston 240gb
I just dont remember the mother.

And yes Intel virtualization is enable in the bios

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use Genymotion? It might have a better performance on your pc. Though trying it won't solve your issue with the virtual device, you may solve your need for an Android emulator to test your apps, which seems to be your main problem.

In the following link you'll find instructions on how to install and use it. It's important to tell that you'll be using VirtualBox but that shouldn't be a problem.

https://docs.genymotion.com/Content/01_Get_Started/Installation.htm

Comment: I want use avd.